# websocket support for javaFx webView

Tags: java, javafx, webview, oracle11g, websocket

is it possible to enable webSocket for javaFx webView, so I can use the chat function of a Url to receive and send messages which is loaded by webView webEngine?

Comment: Hello, did you manage to resolve the issue? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JavaFX WebView supports web sockets.

Here is a sample JavaFX program which loads a web page with web socket features and utilizes them in a WebView.

[image: websocket demo]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebsocketClientExample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        WebView webview = new WebView();
        webview.getEngine().load(
                "http://demos.kaazing.com/echo/index.html"
        );
        webview.setPrefSize(640, 600);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(webview));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thnx for ur support.

Comment: But my Problem is not solved by this. Actually my webView load a Url which have a chat panel and use for chatting. but when i text a message it does not receive at other end at same time until receiver does not refresh the page or reload the page.

Comment: The URL should start with ws:// and not with http://, shouldn't it? Also, I don't see how a websocket server would be created with WebView, as is required in the question

Comment: Well, that's not what your question states Mayank, all you ask is if a WebView supports web sockets, to which the answer is yes.  If you have specific problem with your code such that your implementation is not working for you, then you need to supply the code in the question so that somebody could replicate the issue and help you fix it.  You to supply need a [mcve] in the question which provides a small, complete program that somebody can copy and paste and run without modification to replicate your issue.

Comment: Also, Mayank, when and if you rework your question to provide the [mcve], also provide the public url you communicate with which is hosting your web socket service, or the source code for somebody to build and host that themselves.

Comment: No Jakob, the WebView loads html5 code over http://, so it is correct to use http for that.  Within the web page, the javascript uses the ws:// protocol to connect to the web socket server hosted on the kaazing site.  The WebView is a web socket client, not a web socket server.  There is no need to create a web socket server within the WebView because the web socket server is not running in a JavaFX client application, the web socket server runs on some hosted server somewhere.

Comment: sir jewlsea,  all i want to explain that i just have a web Url which is simply loaded like this:-       webEngine.load(Url);  in my Swing class .                It is loading perfectly but  this web page have a chat option. when I open a chat and text a message to someone, he/she does not receive that message until he/she reload that page or refresh it.                                      I also want to mention that Url is belong to javaScript and I have no code related to that script at my side

Comment: Nobody can help you further unless you provide the code or info to reproduce your error, at a minimum that would include the actual URL you are trying to access.  As you can see with the code I posted, it works fine, web socket messages are sent to the server and received from the server, so it does not and cannot replicate your error.

Comment: here is the code:-       StackPane root = new StackPane();
        WebView webview = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webview.getEngine();
        
        engine.load(Url);
       
        root.getChildren().add(webview);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

Comment: it loads webpage correctly. But when i open chat panel and send text from this webpage message does not delivered/ received at that time.   And when i close chat panel and reopen , it shows the message.

Comment: An [mcve] is a minimal example, that somebody could copy and paste to reproduce the issue without any modification, additions or subtractions.  The code you posted in a comment is not that.  To get a better chance of assistance you need to edit your question to include an mcve, otherwise the chance that somebody would be able to assist you is exceedingly low.